# Swift Protocol: what am i doing wrong?

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

```
@objc protocol Animal{
typealias ElementType
func getSiblings() ->[ElementType]
func getMother() -> ElementType?
func getFather() -> ElementType?
optional func addSibling(sibling:ElementType)
}
```

It keep giving me the error message:  method cannot be marked @objc because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think you can mix `@objc` protocols and protocols with associated types (i.e. that declare a `typealias`).  You can’t declare a stand-alone variable representing a protocol with an associated type – they exist only for use as generic constraints, and generics are a Swift-only thing.  Whereas the purpose of `@objc` protocols are for use in passing into Objective-C functions.  So combining the two doesn’t make sense.

Put it this way – when you pass your `Animal` type into a non-generic Objective-C class, what will the type of `ElementType` be?

Comment: I understand what you are saying but to use optional requirement in protocol with associated type, you need to use @objc. How do I resolve that situation such that optional and typelias coexist?

Comment: I don't think you can. To be honest, the idea of an "optional" protocol method is a bit of a dubious concept. What is the point of a protocol if it doesn't require a method be implemented?  Why include it?

Comment: What you said does make sense. I dont see the point of optional method in a protocol anyway. I just wanted to know if I wasnt missing something.Thanks.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity The addition of optional is what made ObjC protocols useful. Protocols were barely used prior to that addition in ObjC2. They're absolutely critical to how Cocoa manages implements delegation (imagine if you had to implement all 34 `UITableViewDelegate` methods in order to provide any of them). Prior to ObjC2, we generally just added category methods on `NSObject` as an "informal protocol" (which effectively made everything optional).

Comment: But you're probably right that Swift can't mix these features, and probably doesn't want to. A mix of smaller protocols and closures can solve many (though not all) of the problems that optional methods were addressing. (Remember, closures are also pretty new in the Cocoa world.) Not sure, though. If Swift wants to take over the `UITableView`-like objects, it may need optionals to be useful.